# Adding eth0 to openvswitch bridge makes internet stop working

Tags: openvswitch

Adding my eth0 interface to openvswitch bridge with:

```
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
```

makes me unable to accesso to the internet both on the host and , obviously, on the guest.
How to solve this problem? My intention is to connect my virtual machines to the internet forcing them to pass through my openswitch bridge, so to control their traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It guess you must assign your IP to the bridge br0 and set br0 as your new default gateway as soon as eth0 is added to the bridge.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP. I have the bridge ovs-br0 with the same IP as eth0, and ovs-br0 is the default gw